# Displaying columns dynamically Cognos based on SQL Query

Tags: cognos, dynamic-columns

There is a process where a Document / invoice submitted goes through different queues in a workflow. So I have to display all the queues through which a document has gone through dynamically. There are many queues and all documents do not necessarily go through all the queues. Also, there are chances that a doc is returned to a previous queue for some review and that also has to be captured.

For e.g. say the docs move through the queues as below -

`Doc 1  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4

Doc 2   Q1  Q2  Q4  Q5

Doc 3   Q1  Q3  Q5  Q6

Doc 4   Q1  Q2  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4`

So the report output should be as below -

`

```
        Q1 | Q2 | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 | Q6   
Doc 1|  x  | x  |    |    | x  | x  |    |  
Doc 2|  x  | x  |    |    |    | x  | x  |  
Doc 3|  x  |    |    |    | x  |    | x  | x    
Doc 4|  x  | x  | x  |  x | x  |    |    |
```

`

So here, all the column headers are dynamic and I need to show the exit date from each queue which I can manage. Is there a way to dynamically populate the columns based on the SQL query result? The SQL query result would be as below -

DocID   Q_Name  Q_Seq

---

Doc1    Q1  1

Doc1    Q2  2

Doc1    Q3  3

Doc1    Q4  4

Doc2    Q1  1

Doc2    Q2  2

Doc2    Q4  3

Doc2    Q5  4

Hope I have made my question clear. Please let me know if there is a way out. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a crosstab in Cognos? Crosstab columns are dynamic while lists are static.

Comment: I have to show dates under each queue and hence I cannot use a cross tab report.

Comment: Actually, it's possible to use non-numeric data in a crosstab. Check out one of my recent answers that shows how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101741/cross-tabulate-non-numeric-data-in-cognos-bi/52170265#52170265